# Deploy Umbraco v4 site on .net3.5 or .net4.7

Tags: class, umbraco, .net-2.0

I have an old Umbraco website (v4.0.1) that works on Windows Server 2012, IIS 8.5, .net2.0 classic. I now want to deploy the site onto a shared windows server running .net4.7 / .net3.5 in classic or integrated modes. I have tried the configurations in Plesk but I am getting several errors eg 500, object not set to the instance of an object etc. The hosting company are not willing to install .net2.0 is there a way of getting the sites to work on the hosting without .net2.0? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have now replaced the web config and running the site under .net 4.7.2 in integrated mode, but now i get redirected to the umbraco login?

Comment: <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms name="yourAuthCookie" loginUrl="login.aspx" protection="All" path="/"/>
        </authentication>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="?"/>
        </authorization>